# Alias that transforms a template type to the same type but templated on something different

Tags: c++, templates, alias

I have a

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct A;
```

and a

```
template <typename U>
struct B;
```

How do I make an alias that transforms an `A<T, U>` type to a `A<T, B<U>>` type? i.e. something that looks like this:

```
template <typename TypeA>
using ModifiedTypeA = TypeA<T, B<U>>; // <--- I don't know how to get T and U from TypeA
```

where `ModifiedTypeA` only needs to be templated on `TypeA`?

I was thinking that the above could be achieved if `TypeA` is always guaranteed to have member aliases

```
template <typename T_, typename U_>
struct A
{
  using T = T_;
  using U = U_;
};
```

and then do

```
template <typename TypeA>
using ModifiedTypeA = TypeA<typename TypeA::T, B<typename TypeA::U>>;
```

But is there another cleaner way + that doesn't make the above assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
template <typename TypeA, template<typename> typename TemplateB>
struct ModifiedTypeAWtihImpl;

template <template<typename, typename> typename TemplateA, 
          typename T, typename U,
          template<typename> typename TemplateB>
struct ModifiedTypeAWtihImpl<TemplateA<T, U>, TemplateB> {
  using type = TemplateA<T, TemplateB<U>>;
};

template <typename TypeA, template<typename> typename TemplateB>
using ModifiedTypeAWtih = typename ModifiedTypeAWtihImpl<TypeA, TemplateB>::type;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bzqG5xoPK)

Comment: That is almost doing what I'd like - however the above is not assuming a generic A type in the `ModifiedTypeAImpl` definition, right? Say we have an `A1` struct and an `A2` struct, that both could pass as the `TypeA` template parameter, how would one use `ModifiedTypeA<A1<int, char>>` and `ModifiedTypeA<A2<int, char>>` without specializing for both `A1` and `A2`?

Comment: @zhanginou Updated (assume you also want to accept a generic B type.).